# wordpress clone is not running on web matrix 2

Tags: mysql, wordpress, git, clone, webmatrix

I have cloned wordpress site over git.
And I am trying to work on local copy with WebMatrix 2 but when I run the site I get blank page and only favicon is showing correctly.
I guess it is because of databases. How to make it work if I have access only to git clone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a msql database running somewhere :)  Where did you get this WordPress repo from?  Does it have a *.sql file scripted out somewhere so you can do a restore?  Or are you trying to connect to a mysql database that's already running on another server?